# Parse Dashboard is blank

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, parse-server

I've set up of Parse-Server with mongodb on same instance, in amazon, EC2.

I can't get acess to parse-dashboard because I didn't install SSL certificate, so I used nginx + Let's Encrypt to solve this.

But now when I try to acess parse-server I get:

Cannot Get login

How to solve this ? Here is my dashboard config:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
        "serverURL": "http://mysvrurl/parse", 
        "appId": "myappid",
        "masterKey": "mykey",
        "appName": "appname"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "user":"user", 
      "pass":"p@ssw0rd"
    }
```

My index.js:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myappid',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'mykey', //Ad$
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',$
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support f$

 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

before i get all technical, may i know a few information about your server?

1. Did you setup your parse server using Elastic Beanstalk? or just creating a new amazon linux EC2 instance?
2. If you use Elastic Beanstalk, does your Elastic beanstalk dashboard says health: Ok ? or it states severe, warning, bad etc?
3. If you used Elastic Beanstalk to setup your parse-server, your settings for the serverURL in your above code should be localhost instead of any other link. > http://localhost:1337/parse
4. If possible, paste your index.js here and i can help you take a look at it.

   Edit:

   ```
   var allowInsecureHTTP = true;
   var parseDashboardSettings = {
     "apps": [{
       "serverURL": process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',
       "appId": process.env.APP_ID || '***',
       //"restAPIKey": process.env.RESTAPI_KEY || "***",
       "masterKey": process.env.MASTER_KEY || '***',
       "appName": process.env.APP_NAME || "***"
     }],
     "users": [{
       "user": "administrator", //REPLACE WITH YOURS
       "pass": "password", //REPLACE WITH YOURS
       "masterKey": process.env.MASTER_KEY || '****',
       "apps": [{
         "appId": process.env.APP_ID || '****'
       }]
     }]
   }
   var dashboard = new ParseDashboard(parseDashboardSettings, allowInsecureHTTP);
   app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);
   ```

Comment: 1. I created a new EC2 instance 4. I edit with index.js

Comment: This part: 'var dashboard = new ParseDashboard(parseDashboardSettings, allowInsecureHTTP);
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);' go in the final of document ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try doing the following steps
In chrome
open Settings --> Go to Site settings -->Click on Insecure Content --> Click on "Add" button corresponding to "Allow" copy and paste your Public IPv4 DNS in the address box
it worked for me